# 'Unable to open X display' error is produced by a CEF application running in windowless (off screen rendering) mode

Tags: chromium-embedded

[01] The application was built and executed in a docker.
     The Dockerfile is as follows:

```
>>>>

    FROM ubuntu:xenial

    RUN apt-get update  -y 
    RUN apt-get install -y wget
    RUN apt-get install -y apt-utils

    RUN apt-get install -y python3
    RUN apt-get install -y tree
    RUN apt-get install build-essential software-properties-common -y

    RUN apt-get -y install libgtk2.0-dev
    RUN apt-get -y install libgtkglext1-dev

    RUN apt-get -y install python3-pip
    RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip

    RUN apt-get -y install cmake
    RUN pip3 install --upgrade cmake

    RUN apt-get -y install libnss3-dev
    RUN apt-get -y install libxtst6
    RUN apt-get -y install libxss1
    RUN apt-get -y install libasound2
    RUN apt-get -y install libatk-bridge2.0-0

<<<<

the CEF binary being used is
cef_binary_76.1.5+gd8a577c+chromium-76.0.3809.87_linux64/
```

[02] the application worked fine when starting the docker
     with xhost+ and -e DISPLAY=.... as follows:

```
[A] starting docker with bash

xhost +
docker run \
        -it \
        --rm \
        -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY
        --privileged \
        -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix \
        ...
        --network host \
        --name $CONTAINER_NAME \
        $REQD_IMAGE \
        bash

[B] running the application in bash as

onpaint_streamer \
    --no-sandbox \
    --disable-gpu \
    --disable-gpu-compositing \
    --enable-begin-frame-scheduling \
    --disable-extensions \
    --disable-pdf-extension \
    --url=file:///test/027/test.html
```

[03] the application DID NOT WORK when xhost+ and -e DISPLAY=.... 
     were removed in [02][A]. The following message was dumped

```
+ ./onpaint_streamer --no-sandbox --disable-gpu --disable-gpu-compositing --enable-begin-frame-scheduling --disable-extensions --disable-pdf-extension --opg-fifo-path=/adhyuh/test/027/onpaint_data_fifo --opg-verbose --url=file:///test/027/test.html
d> CefInitialize : status=about_to
[0812/140301.641476:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(1504)] Unable to open X display.
d> CefInitialize : status=done
d> MessageLoop : status=started
[0812/140301.641921:FATAL:context.cc(584)] Check failed: CEF_CURRENTLY_ON(content::BrowserThread::UI). 
./run_onpaint_data_writer_in_dk.sh: line 32:    20 Trace/breakpoint trap   (core dumped) ./$STREAMER_APP --no-sandbox --disable-gpu --disable-gpu-compositing --enable-begin-frame-scheduling --disable-extensions --disable-pdf-extension --url=file:///test/027/test.html
```

[04] Some of the other 'flags' embedded in the code are

```
void SimpleApp::OnContextInitialized() {

  //....

  CefBrowserSettings browser_settings;
  browser_settings.windowless_frame_rate = 30;

  CefWindowInfo window_info;
  window_info.SetAsWindowless(0);

  //....
}
```

[05] Why should a windowless CEF application require xhost and DISPLAY to be present ? What am i missing or doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

*CEF depends on X11 library even in windowless mode ...* was the answer that i got when a similar post was raised in CEF Forums. Please see https://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=16993&sid=5e46cc6bfb909badf63e0aafcfe9413f&p=42879#p42879

Answer (score 0):

For me, adding `--headless` made that X display message go away when running in docker.